# Model Validation On Nested View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view , data listing in this view . When user select a row , form posting to ajax action and this action returns the row details to partial view.

User doing arrangements the row details and submit form to another action.Model validating at this action and i must return model errors to validatesummary.

But i could not this becouse if i add the model error and return partial view, my main view of course  does not showing and only shows partial view.

I want add model error to partial view inside the view. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

replace your data list (or the grid) ourside the `<form></form>` or `@html.BeginForm(){}`. 
Then the problem will be solved